# stack arround variable corrupted

Tags: c, visual-c++

when running this code, I code error : stack around variable `window_text_hex` corrupted. I can't see the error?

```
DWORD WINAPI fill_matrix(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    char window_text_hex[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        int data_j = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <8; j++)
        {   

            char window_text[5] = { mySerial.data[i][data_j], mySerial.data[i][data_j + 1], mySerial.data[i][data_j + 2], mySerial.data[i][data_j + 3], '\0' };
            for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            {
                sprintf(&window_text_hex[i], "%02X", window_text[i]);
            }
            SetWindowTextA(hWndLabel[i * 8 + j], window_text_hex);
            data_j += 4;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

mySerial.data is an array of [8][36]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your for loop, `i` can be `3`.

You're `sprintf`ing to `window_text_hex+3`, which has room for **two** bytes (`window_text_hex[3]`, `windows_text_hex[4]`).

`sprintf` `%02X` writes at least **three** bytes: Two hex digits and a `'\0'` terminator.
(Since you're passing a `char`, it may actually write much more. `char` is often a signed type, but `%X` expects an `unsigned int`. So negative inputs (like `-1`) produce long outputs (`FFFFFFFF`). Fix: `(unsigned char)window_text[i]`.)

You're writing past the end of your `window_text_hex` array.